# Read XML from RSS using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rss, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to read a RSS from this URL http://www.vworker.com/RentACoder/misc/LinkToUs/RssFeed_newBidRequests.asp?blnAllOpen=true using JavaScript. I'm trying to XMLHttpReq to do it but its not working.

```
url="http://www.vWorker.com/RentACoder/misc/LinkToUs/RssFeed_newBidRequests.asp?blnAllOpen=true";
   var xmlhttp = null;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
   {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      if ( typeof xmlhttp.overrideMimeType != 'undefined') 
      {
         xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
      }
   } 
   else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
   {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   } 
   else 
   {
      alert('Perhaps your browser does not support xmlhttprequests?');
   }

   xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
   xmlhttp.send(null);
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
   {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
       {
        alert("success");
       }
       else 
       {
        alert("failure");
       }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're being limited by same origin restrictions. Could you build an intermediary (like a php script on your domain that would pull in the RSS?) then you'd change your url to that script

```
<?php
$x=file_get_contents('http://www.vworker.com/RentACoder/misc/LinkToUs/RssFeed_newBidRequests.asp?blnAllOpen=true');
echo $x;
 ?>
```